# C# Windows 10 App - Draw Line Slowly From X1, Y1 to X2,Y2

Tags: c#, animation, line

I am struggling with this problem that should be fairly easy to solve. I want to simply specify the X1 and Y1 and X2 and Y2 coordinates for a line on a canvas and have a line drawn between those points over a period of 1 second.

My canvas name is cnvML and the name of the line is L1. This needs to be done at runtime, so I would prefer to use C#, but if I can modify a named storyboard that is created in XAML, that is fine. I am assuming I need a Storyboard, although I haven't been able to get that to work. 
Here is what I have tried over the last 2 days:

1. Scoured google for lots of examples. I have been able to animate lines, rectangles, and ellipses across the canvas by changing the X and Y properties of the Animation. I have not been able to figure out how to transform the X2 and Y2 properties of the line itself. I have seen some examples of this for older frameworks, but the constructors for some of the methods are different and will not work for Windows 10 apps.
2. I have tried building an animation in Blend, but it only works for animating lines that are built at design time. It gives me an error if I don't specify the Target of the animation. Also, doing it in Blend isn't really accomplishing the transform the way I want. If I start at time 0 with a very short line, then at 1 second, I stretch the line out to the desired length, it is changing the scale of the line, thereby changing the apparent stroke thickness of the path object.

I would really appreciate it if someone can show me how to do this, maybe even without using a storyboard. And I would like it to be all in C#. The canvas, named cnvML will exist at design time, but the lines will be created at run time.

Again, I would like to just pass to a method the X1, Y1, X2, and Y2 to a method. Then the line would be drawn and take 1 second to be drawn between those 2 points.

Thanks,
David

Comment: OK, after a bit of reading... Create a `Line` object, set `X2` and `Y2` at the same values as `X1` and `Y1`, then use a couple of `DoubleAnimation` elements in a storyboard to change their value over time to where they need to be.  Never done it, but it sounds like it should work :D

Comment: Hi Corey. Thanks for the comment. Yes, I agree with you that it should work, but how do you do this? I tried Storyboard.SetTargetProperty((Timeline)doubleAnimationX, new PropertyPath( "(Line.X2)").ToString()); But as you see here, it wants a String for the second argument, and the compiler says it cannot find property X2.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote from whoever did it with no explanation. I thought I did a pretty good job of explaining what I wanted. I know I didn't show the code, but as I stated in my original post, the only thing I have been able to do so far is move rectangles, lines, and ellipses. I didn't think there was any reason to show code that does that when that is not what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't WPF, so this was cobbled together from examples found elsewhere.

Using a storyboard you can animate the `X2` and `Y2` properties like this:

```
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="line1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X2" From="10" To="100" Duration="0:0:1.0"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="line1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y2" From="10" To="100" Duration="0:0:1.0"/>
    </Storyboard>
```

How you kick that off is up to you.  I just added it to a button control's `Button.Click` event trigger.

What this does is the equivalent of a linear interpolation across time of the target property, so in this example over the course of a second the values of `X1` and `Y1` will vary smoothly between `11` and `100`.  This will give the appearance of the line extending from its origin point (at `10,10` in my test version) along the line towards the final endpoint at `100,100`.

Here's the full XAML of my test.  Since I don't WPF I expect that there are probably several things I could have done better :)

```
<Window x:Class="AnimTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AnimTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="426">
            <Line Name="line1" X1="10" Y1="10" X2="10" Y2="10" StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="Black"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Button Margin="441,279,10,10">
            OK
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="line1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X2" From="10" To="100" Duration="0:0:1.0"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="line1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y2" From="10" To="100" Duration="0:0:1.0"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

I installed the Universal App tools and tried it out.  Turns out they changed a whole bunch of things in Universal Apps as compared to WPF, including pretty much scrapping the concept of routed events in XAML.  That sounds like a great way to annoy a vast number of developers, huh?

So now instead of being able to give a XAML-only answer that works for WPF, here's a two-part XAML + Code answer for Universal (on W10, VS2015):

First the XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="UniversalApp1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UniversalApp1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="btnClick_SB" >
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="line1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X2" From="10" To="400" Duration="0:0:1.0" EnableDependentAnimation="True"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="line1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y2" From="10" To="400" Duration="0:0:1.0" EnableDependentAnimation="True"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Margin="10,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="426">
            <Line Name="line1" X1="10" Y1="10" X2="10" Y2="10" StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="Black"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Button Margin="441,279,10,10" Click="Button_Click">OK</Button>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And the (relevant part of the) code:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btnClick_SB.Stop();
        btnClick_SB.Begin();
    }
```

The `btnClick_SB.Stop()` call ensures that you don't invoke the storyboard while it is already running, which is apparently a forbidden action that will throw an exception.

Comment: thanks for the effort. I really do appreciate it, but it didn't work. I can tell based on your XML that you are not using VS 2015 to build a Universal App. Apparently there are some big differences from VS 2015 and 2013 or earlier. First of all, your RoutedEvents was invalid for me. The only RoutedEvent for Windows 10 apps is FrameWorkElement.Loaded. Here is some more info on that https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.eventtrigger.routedevent

I guess your code does work for earlier versions of Windows. I didn't see any animations. Still searching for answers.

Comment: That was a standard WPF application in VS2015 on Windows 10.  Universal apps are very different I believe.